# Word for this type of question?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am wondering if there is a word that characterizes this specific type of question.

Given this series of questions, it would be *understood* that one must continue answering if the answer is no, or stop once the answer is yes.

Example (the question **type** would *imply* the parenthetical instructions):

> - Can you do A? (If no, proceed. If yes, stop.)
> - (If no,) Can you do B? (If no, proceed. If yes, stop.)
> - (If no,) Can you do C? (If no, proceed. If yes, stop.)
>
> The following is a [**TYPE**] question:
>
> - In forum X, can I post a message about jobs?
> - In forum X, can I post a message asking about forums where I can post about jobs?
> - Can I get some information about a forum where I *can* post a message about jobs?

Comment: Perhaps you might consider *This is a **terminal** question*  But I don't think anyone would understand what that meant without explanation.  I'm not sure there is any such single word that would be universally interpreted the way you wish.

Comment: This reminds me of the term "drilldown questionnaire". But the term *drilldown* cannot be found in any dictionaries that I know of.

Comment: A **Heuristic** question?

Comment: It's a [switch statement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm).

Comment: @Susan excellent editing. I am impressed! Thank you

Comment: @John Lawler Although I was not thinking about using this type of question in a programming setting, I recognized computer programming has this tool. In a non-programming context, perhaps we start using "The following is a switch statement: Can you ..." I guess the case would be the A, B, C. Although not very flexible

Comment: @Autoresponder, if the question is in writing, I guess prefabricated, I think heuristic would not apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a word describing this type of question. When I see these, they are usually preceded by an explanation, such as, continue to answer until you reach a question whose answer is "yes".

Sometimes each question has a direction: "If no, proceed to next question."

Answer (score 0):

How about a conditional or disjunctive question?

Answer (score 0):

These are often referred to as **[branching questions](http://www.surveywriter.com/in/help/SW-QuestionBranching.htm)**.